# prolog interpreter on linux?

Tags: prolog

I've decided to learn prolog. What's a good interpreter to use? Even better if it has a decent c/c++ ffi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend [GNU Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/), because that seems to be the standard, but I've also heard good things about [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/).

Answer (score 3):

[GNU Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/) sounds like a decent starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [ECLiPSe](http://87.230.22.228/index.html).